# (Feedback on a proof) Prove that the spans of two linearly independent lists (of the same length) themselves have the same length.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am currently studying linear algebra without a great source of feedback on my proofs and would therefore really appreciate some feedback on the below proof. Particularly the validity of my conclusion about deriving the number of possibilities. Note that I tried to prove this with minimal use of theorems.

$\textbf{Proposition:}$ Given $F$-vector space $V$,  $v_1,...,v_n\in V, v_1^{'},...,v_n^{'}\in V, \{v_1,...,v_n\}$ is linearly independant,  $\{v_1^{'},...,v_n^{'}\}$ is linearly independant, $\#\{v_1,...,v_n\} = \#\{v_1^{'},...,v_n^{'}\}$ then $\#span(v_1,...,v_n)=\#span(v_1^{'},...,v_n^{'})$

Take arbitrary $w_1, w_2\in span(v_1,...,v_n), w_1=a_1v_1+...+a_nv_n,  w_2 = a_1^{'}v_1+...+a_n^{'}v_n, a_1,...,a_n, a_1^{'},...,a_n^{'} \in F$. We begin by showing that when $w_1=w_2$, we must have that $a_1,...,a_n = a_1^{'},...,a_n^{'}$

Proof by contradiction. Assume $a_1,...,a_n \neq a_1^{'},...,a_n^{'}$ with $w_1=w_2 \Rightarrow a_1v_1+...+a_nv_n, = a_1^{'}v_1+...+a_n^{'}v_n$. This gives us that $0 = a_1v_1+...+a_nv_n - (a_1^{'}v_1+...+a_n^{'}v_n) \Rightarrow 0 = (a_1-a_1^{'})v_1+(a_n-a_n^{'})v_n$, and since  $a_1,...,a_n \neq a_1^{'},...,a_n^{'}$, at least one of these coefficients $\neq 0$ and this violates the given statement that $v_1,...,v_n$ is a linearly independant set.

Therefore we have that for each possible combination of $a_1,...,a_n \in F$ we produce a unique $v \in V$ with $v = a_1v_1+...+a_nv_n \Rightarrow$ we $\#$unique $v$'s equal to the number of combinations of $a_1,...,a_n \Rightarrow$ we have that for arbitrary vectors $\in span(v_1,...,v_n), span(v_1^{'},...,v_n^{'})$ we have number of possible outcomes equal to the number of possible combinations for $a_1,...,a_n \Rightarrow$ we have our desired result.

$\square$

Comment: No need to check the "proof": the result is false...unless $\;\dim V=n\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio why is this the case?

Comment: @Thornside Take for example $\;V=\Bbb R^2\;,\;\;v_1=\binom10\;,\;\;v_1'=\binom01\;$ . Then each of $\;\{v_1\}\;,\;\;\{v_1'\}\;$ is l.i., but of course $\;Span\{v_1\}\neq Span\{v_1'\}\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm concerned here with comparing the cardinality of $Span\{v_1\}$ and $Span\{v_1^{'}\}$ which I'd think would be the same.

Comment: Oh, I see: by $\;$#$...\;$ you mean "the cardinality" of those sets and not equality between those sets...! Then the result is true and pretty trivial. I shall now check your proof.

Comment: Please, type `v'` and not `v^{'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much quicker way would be to prove that the linear mapping

$$f:\operatorname{span}\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}\to\operatorname{span}\{v_1',\dots,v_n'\}$$

which maps $f(v_i)=v_i'$ (this is uniquely determined) is a bijection, so let's do this. Let

$$x=\lambda_1v_1+\dots+\lambda_nv_n$$
$$y=\mu_1v_1+\dots+\mu_nv_n$$

be such that $f(x)=f(y)$. Notice that, by linearity,

$$f(x)=f(\lambda_1v_1+\dots+\lambda_nv_n)=\lambda_1f(v_1)+\dots+\lambda_nf(v_n)=\lambda_1v_1'+\dots+\lambda_nv_n'$$

and similarly

$$f(y)=\mu_1v_1'+\dots+\mu_nv_n'.$$

Thus, by the fact that $f(x)-f(y)=0$, we have that

$$(\lambda_1-\mu_1)v_1'+\dots+(\lambda_n-\mu_n)v_n'=0,$$

and as $v_1',\dots,v_n'$ are linearly independent, it follows that $\lambda_i=\mu_i$ for all $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$. Thus $x=y$, and so $f$ is injective. Now let $v=\xi_1v_1'+\dots+\xi_nv_n'$. Then $w=\xi_1v_1+\dots+\xi_nv_n$ is such that $f(w)=v$. Thus $f$ is bijective, and it follows that

$$\lvert\operatorname{span}\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}\rvert=\lvert\operatorname{span}\{v_1',\dots,v_n'\}\rvert.$$

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to prove that both sets have *the same cardinality*, your proof is incorrect as you begin by trying to prove that $\;w_1=w_2\;$ , which in general won't be true (probably this misled me to understand you wanted to prove equality of sets instead of their cardinals...). To convince yourself of this take my example in the comments: the only element common to both spans is the zero vector...!

I propose the following: every element in $\;Span\{v_1,...,v_n\}\,,\,Span\{v_1',...,v_n'\}\;$ has a unique representation as linear combination of these vectors, as they are l.i., so define a function

$$f:Span\{v_1,...,v_n\}\to Span\{v_1',...,v_n'\},\;\; f\left(\sum_{k=1}^na_kv_k\right):= \sum_{k=1}^na_kv_k'$$

I'll leave to you to check the above is a *bijection* (i.e. injective and surjective) and thus you get your result.